# On Partitions Assignment and ChainedKafkaTransactionManager at startup with JPA

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-transactions, spring-kafka

I have many transactional consumers with a `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` based on a `JpaTransactionManager` and a `KafkaTransactionManager` (all `@KafkaListener`'s).

The JPA one needs a ThreadLocal variable to be set, to be able to know to which DB to connect to (is the tenant id).

When starting the application, in the `onPartitionsAssigned` [listener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L2223), spring-kafka is trying to create a chained txn, hence trying to create a JPA txn, but there's no tenant set, then it fails.

That tenant is set through a http filter and/or kafka interceptors (through event headers).

I tried using the auto-wired `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` with `setAutoStartup(false)`, but I see that the consumers don't receive any events, probably because they aren't initialized yet (I thought they were initialized on-demand).

If I set a mock tenant id and call `registry.start()` when the application is ready, the initializations seem to be done in other threads (probably because I'm using a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`), so it doesn't work.

Is there a way to avoid the JPA transaction on that initial `onPartitionsAssigned` listener, that is part of the consumer initialization?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The same thread(s) that will eventually call the listener when records are received call the `onPartitionsAssigned()` first. If the TL is not set up for that then it won't be when calling the listener either. What sets up the TL, and when?

Comment: I edited the question trying to be clearer. Ideally, I'd like the consumer initialization to be done without JPA, and the normal pub/sub with the chained txn manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your chained TM has the KafkaTM first, followed by JPA TM (which would be the normal case), you can achieve similar functionality by just injecting the Kafka TM into the container and using `@Transactional` (with just the JPA TM on the listener) to start the JPA transaction when the listener is called.

The time between the transaction commits will be marginally increased but it would provide similar functionality.

If that won't work for you, open a GitHub issue; we can either disable the initial commit on assignment, or do it without a transaction at all (optionally).

Comment: You mean adding `@Transactional` to all transactional `@KafkaListener`'s right? Similar or equal? Because we have a pretty intensive EDA, and we rely on the transaction-ability between jpa and kafka to have local consistency. May I open the issue to have the other options?

Comment: Yes; please open the issue; we should add the options. Using `@Transactional` in this case is virtually the same; with the CKTM (assuming the KTM is first), we start the KTx, then the JPATx, then call the listener; when the method exits, the JPATx is committed, followed by the KTx. With just the KTM in the container and the JPATM in the `@Transactional`, we start the KTx, call the listener, the transaction interceptor starts the JPATx and then the actual listener is called; when the listener exits normally, the interceptor commits JPA, when the interceptor exits, the container commits the KTx.

Comment: All that being said, if you are NOT writing to Kafka (as well as JPA), Kafka transactions don't really buy you anything except some extra overhead.

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1370. Thank you!